# Product Gallery cloudinary

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to implement a product gallery for a project. The owner asked me that the gallery is "the same" as that of amazon.

Doing some research I found this cloudinary, which would be the case.

Does anyone know if there is a code snippet that reproduces this behavior?

https://demo.cloudinary.com/product-gallery/

Comment: Usually questions asking for resources are not allowed, so I tried to give a quick answer to help you out. I think a reference list of carousel/slider plugins or gallery plugins on stackoverflow is not a bad idea either.

Answer (score 0):

Use something lie a slider plugin, e.g. Swiper slider https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper

It has pretty much all the functionality any other plugin has. Other than that, owl carousel, flex slider are some other popular ones.

If you mean a simple image gallery, look up for gallery plugins on github, e.g. this one: https://github.com/desandro/masonry